Two formal adjoints of $\nabla^A:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)$.
$\newcommand{\dvolg}{\operatorname{dvol}_g}$Let $(M,g)$ be a closed orientable Riemannian manifold, and $(E,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle,\nabla^A)$ be a vector bundle over $M$ equipped with a bundle metric, and a metric compatible covariant derivative $\nabla^A$. The operator $\nabla^A$ is a derivation $\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)$, and since $g$ and $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle_E$ induce a bundle metric on $E\otimes T^*M$, it makes sense to want to try and find a formal adjoint $\nabla^{A*}:\Gamma(E)\otimes\Gamma(T^*M)\rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ which satisfies:
\begin{align*}
  \int_M\langle \nabla^A\Phi,\alpha\rangle_{E\otimes T^*M}\dvolg=\int_M\langle \Phi, \nabla^{A*}\alpha\rangle_E\dvolg
\end{align*}
Now I already know of such of map. Indeed, consider the exterior covariant derivative, $d_A:\Omega^p(M,E)\rightarrow \Omega^{p+1}(M,E)$ given on simple tensors by:
\begin{align}
d_A(\omega\otimes \Phi)=d\omega\otimes \Phi+(-1)^p\omega\wedge \nabla^A\Phi
\end{align}
By noting that $ \Omega^0(M,E)$ and $\Omega^1(M,E)$ are just $\Gamma(E)$ and $\Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)$, respectively, we have that $d_A$ acting on sections is just the $\nabla^A$. Moreover, this has a formal adjoint for all $p$ given by:
$$d_A^*=(-1)^{np+1}\star d_A\star$$
where $\star$ is the Hodge star operator. In this sense, $d_A^\star$, acting on $\Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)$ is the formal adjoint of $\nabla^A$.
However, I was looking at some result that was talking about the formal adjoint of a spin connection on a Clifford algebra bundle, and it incorporated the Levi-Civita connection. This got me thinking about natural maps $\Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)\rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ which incorporate the Levi-Civita connection, and their properties. There is an induced connection $\Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)\rightarrow \Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)^{\otimes 2}$ given by:
\begin{align}
\nabla':\Phi \otimes \xi&\longmapsto \nabla^A\Phi\otimes \xi+\Phi\otimes \nabla \xi
\end{align}
where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connnection. There is then a natural $C^\infty(M)$ linear map $\Gamma(E)\otimes \Gamma(T^*M)^{\otimes 2}\rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ given by:
\begin{align}
f:\Phi\otimes \xi\otimes \beta&\longmapsto \Phi\cdot\langle \xi,\beta  \rangle_{T^*M}
\end{align}
I now define $\nabla^{A*}$ to be $\alpha\longmapsto -f(\nabla'\alpha)$.
This is also seems to be a formal adjoint. Indeed if I define $\omega$ to be the one form on $M$ given by:
\begin{align}
\omega(X)=\langle \Phi,\alpha(X)\rangle_E
\end{align}
then I can show that for all $x\in M$:
\begin{align}
(\nabla^A\Phi,\alpha\rangle_{E\otimes T^*M}-\langle \Phi, \nabla^{A*}\alpha\rangle_E)_x=(\star d\star \omega)_x
\end{align}
so $\nabla^{A*}$ is the formal adjoint because $(\nabla^A\Phi,\alpha\rangle_{E\otimes T^*M}-\langle \Phi, \nabla^{A*}\alpha\rangle_E)\dvolg$ is exact.
Are these two operators somehow equal (which would surprise me as $\nabla^{A*}$ involves Christoffel symbols), or have I made a grave error somewhere?
